TYPO3 tx_news linkhandler & multiple storageIDs
I´m trying to get the tx_news linkhandler running. Problem: the newsentries are in two sysfolders.
I tried:
# tx_news is an identifier, don't change it after links have been created
TCEMAIN.linkHandler.tx_news {
   handler = TYPO3\CMS\Backend\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
   # A translatable label can be used with LLL:EXT:theme/locallang.xml:label
   label = News
   configuration {
      table = tx_news_domain_model_news
      # Default storage pid
      storagePid = 123,456
      # Hide the page tree by setting it to 1
      hidePageTree = 0
   }
   scanAfter = page
}

But works only for the second ID.
Is there a trick to fix that?
Thanks!
News from both sysfolders should be available in the linkhandler.

This should do the job:
# tx_news is an identifier, don't change it after links have been created
TCEMAIN.linkHandler.tx_news {
    handler = TYPO3\CMS\Backend\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
    # A translatable label can be used with LLL:EXT:theme/locallang.xml:label
    label = News
    configuration {
        table = tx_news_domain_model_news
        # Default storage pid
        storagePid = 123
        pageTreeMountPoints = 123,456
        # Hide the page tree by setting it to 1
        hidePageTree = 0
    }
    scanAfter = page
}


works perfectly, thank you a lot!
